# ifelse() combined with stop() throws unexpected error (R)

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I want to create a new column in a `data.table` with some nested `ifelse()` statements: I included a control with `stop()` at the end, which should never be reached. In my exampled either `condition_a` or `condition_b` has to be `"Y"`. The `stop()` should never be reached, but it does. Can someone explain this to me?

Example code:

```
library(data.table)

condition_a <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
condition_b <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N")

dt <- data.table(condition_a, condition_b)

dt <-
  dt[, conditions := ifelse(test = ((condition_a == "Y") &
                                      (condition_b == "Y")),
                            yes = "a_and_b",
                            no = ifelse(test = ((condition_a == "N") &
                                                  (condition_b == "Y")),
                                        yes = "b",
                                        no = ifelse(test = ((condition_a == "Y") &
                                                              (condition_b == "N")),
                                                    yes = "a",
                                                    no = ifelse(test = ((condition_a == "N") &
                                                                          (condition_b == "N")),
                                                                yes = stop('double "N" found'),
                                                                no = stop("this should not happen")))))]
```

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Why do you want to put a `stop` there? I don't think that makes a lot of sense for an `ifelse` statement. couldn't you just return the string?

Comment: I want to stop there, because it should not happen that in one row there is "N" and "N", and neither that there is an entry that is not "N" or "Y". But I guess I found the solution. The brackets are evaluated inside out and not top to bottom. So, there is noe exit from the innermost bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtained an error because `ifelse` often evaluates all its arguments (but not always: there are edges cases where there is no evaluation like in `ifelse(test=c(1, NA)==c(NA, 1), stop("notEval"), stop("notEavl"))`; note that in this particular case, the `test` argument evaluates to only `NA`s).

If you would like to evaluate an argument only when it's necessary, you should use the data.table function `fcase`, which is a nice and smart implementation of nested ifelse.

```
dt[, conditions := fcase(condition_a == "Y" & condition_b == "Y", "a_and_b",
                         condition_a == "N" & condition_b == "Y", "b",
                         condition_a == "Y" & condition_b == "N", "a",
                         condition_a == "N" & condition_b == "N", stop('double "N" found'))]
```

In this case, the statement with `stop` will never be evaluated because the there is no case where `condition_a == "N" & condition_b == "N"` evaluates to `TRUE` in `dt`.

Also note that data.table works by reference; so, there is no need to reassign your data.table when using `:=`. that is, `dt[, conditions := ...]` will add a new column to `dt`. you don't need to use the assignment operator `<-` like in `dt <- dt[, conditions := ...]`.